# Print a page content in yii2

Tags: javascript, html, yii2-advanced-app

I am facing a problem with print page contents. I have used `window.print()`, but it prints the whole window. I just need to take print of some contents in my page. Please provide me a solution.

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function printContent(el)
      {
         var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
         var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
         document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
         window.print();
         document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
     }
   </script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <h1>My page</h1>
    <div id="div1">DIV 1 content...</div>
    <button onclick="printContent('div1')">Print Content</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I  use my print function inside the div of the content i am able to print the content page.